# Escape $id$-string in file

Tags: cvs

I´m writing some code-generator. Every source-code-file generated by this should start with the special cvs-command `$id$` which gets replaced by CVS on checkin.

So I have this code:

```
code.Comments.Add(new CodeCommentStatement("$Id$"));
```

Where `code` is of type `System.CodeDom.CodeNamespace`.

However the codegenerator itself is hosted on our version-control-system and thus the `"$id"`-part within my generators source-code gets replaced on checkin as well.

How can I escape the sequence so that the string does not get replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split it up or create a variable. Something like this. (Forgive my possibly incorrect java syntax.)

```
code.Comments.Add(new CodeCommentStatement("$I" + "d$"));
```

or

```
var dollar='$';
code.Comments.Add(new CodeCommentStatement(dollar+"Id"+dollar));
```

While you could also make that script file binary in cvs (`-kb`), I don't think that's advisable.

Comment: The best ideas are those you don´t have. Thanks for this simple but brilliant answer.